# How to set timeout in javascript swagger generated client?

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0

I put javascript swagger generated client successfully into React project and everything is working fine. I am generating this client by [online editor](http://editor.swagger.io). Now I need to set timeouts.

**Is it possible to change timeouts without changing the generated code?** Or does exist any other javascript client generator which can I use to generate more robust JS client?

Comment: I think you'll need to provide more information... maybe a code sample of what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: All you need is to go [here](http://editor.swagger.io/) and generate JS client by "Generate client/Javascript" from template API. You can include generated JS client into every Javascript project.

Comment: Recently, there's been a lot of enhancements to JS API client generated by [swagger-codegen](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen) but I don't think the JS API client allows setting the HTTP timeout for `superagent`. Other API clients (e.g. PHP, C#) already allows that. Please file a ticket [here](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues) for the feature request.

Comment: Finally, we made a pull request to `swagger-codegen` project with my colleague and it has been merged.

Comment: I have an angular project, and I don't know how to integrate the JS generated client, any tutorial or clue ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By making a PR, we've solved this. Now it is possible to set timeout by this way:

```
yourDefaultApiInstance.apiClient.timeout = timeoutInMillis;
```